# How to solve find a formula of homogeneous recurrence relation?

Tags: linear-algebra, recurrence-relations, homogeneous-equation

I try to find the formula for the following recurrence relation:

$a_n = 2a_{n-1} + a_{n-2} $

$ a_0 = 1 $

$ a_1 = 3 $

I solve it as follow:

$ a_n - 2a_{n-1} - a_{n-2} = 0 $

$ t^2 - 2t - 1 = 0 $

$ t_1 = 1 - \sqrt{2} $

$ t_2 = \sqrt{2} + 1 $

I need to find values of $A$ and $B$, given the following equations:

$a_0 = A + B = 1$

$a_1 = A(1 - \sqrt{2}) + B(\sqrt{2} + 1) = 3$

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a system of linear equations
\begin{cases}
&A + &B & = 1\\
(1 - \sqrt{2})& A+ (1+\sqrt{2})&B & = 3
\end{cases}

You can use the so-called method of substiution or method of elimination, or any advanced methods including Cramer's rule, Gaussian elimination, LU factorization.

For example, if we would like to use method of elimination, subtracting $1 - \sqrt{2}$ times the first equation from the second equation we have
$$((1+\sqrt{2}) - (1-\sqrt{2}))B = 3 - (1-\sqrt{2})$$
which is
$$2\sqrt{2} B = \sqrt{2} + 2$$
and therefore
$$B = \frac{1}{2}(1 + \sqrt{2})$$
Finally substituting $B = \frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{2} - 1)$ back to the first equation, we have
$$A = \frac{1}{2}(1 - \sqrt{2})$$